# Import local CSS file into a procedure

Tags: css, plsql, import

I got a PL/SQL Web Toolkit project not online (url : http://127.0.0.1:8080/dad/my_procedure).
And I just want to know how to import a local CSS file into this procedure...
I tried to do something like this :

```
htp.print('<link href="'C:/Users/Me/Desktop/css/filecss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
```

or even

```
htp.print('<link href="/css/filecss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
```

with no success...

In reality I don't know what's the root directory for a project like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS file has to be within the HEAD area of the webpage. You should have your htp.print statement between the `htp.headopen` and `htp.headclose` calls.

Also, the CSS file path is relative to the web server processing the request, so the path should be to the directory on the web server that the CSS file resides.

Comment: Ok but if the web server is localhost, how can I use a CSS file residing on my harddrive ?

Comment: Assuming you're using Oracle HTTP Server as your web server, there will be an htdocs folder under the installation directory that serves as the DocumentRoot. Any relative paths you reference will be available under that folder.

Comment: Ok I see ! I searched for any folder htdocs on my computer and didn't find it... Any idea where it can be ?

Comment: It's difficult to know what it will be called and where it will be on your computer without knowing which web server you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Oracle Express Edition

Comment: You need to look a little closer at the software stack you are using, and figure out what web server you are using (i.e. which one is bundled with Oracle XE).